# Chef and redissio error

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-solo

Maybe someone faced with the same situation

We have a clean instance on redis who try to put a chef
Default recipe has only

include_recipe "redisio :: install"

When I cook getting the following error
Enviroment AWS ec2.micro ubuntu 12.04 
When I run cook to receive an error

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/chef-solo/cookbooks/main/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================


NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/chef-solo/cookbooks/ulimit/recipes/default.rb:13:in `block in from_file'
  /tmp/chef-solo/cookbooks/ulimit/recipes/default.rb:12:in `from_file'
  /tmp/chef-solo/cookbooks/redisio/recipes/install.rb:20:in `from_file'
  /tmp/chef-solo/cookbooks/main/recipes/default.rb:11:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/tmp/chef-solo/cookbooks/ulimit/recipes/default.rb:

  6:  # All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
  7:  #
  8:  ulimit = node['ulimit']
  9:  
 10:  case node[:platform]
 11:    when "debian", "ubuntu"
 12:      template "/etc/pam.d/su" do
 13>>       cookbook ulimit['pam_su_template_cookbook'] 
 14:      end
 15:  end
 16:  


[2013-04-06T14:09:50+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-04-06T14:09:50+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2013-04-06T14:09:50+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/chef-solo/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-04-06T14:09:50+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
ERROR: RuntimeError: chef-solo failed. See output above.
```

Resource https://github.com/Piom/redis-chef.git

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well. I have one way to solve it but I am also just started looking into chef.

the issue is redisio depends on ulimit and looks like the recipe does not handle when you don't have any attributes for ulimit defined.

```
ulimit = node['ulimit']
```

try to get a hash of attributes but is getting nil. So if you define some attributes it should work.

there might be an updated version of the recipe since you downloaded it. If not in `ulimit/attributes/default.rb` I have `default['ulimit']['pam_su_template_cookbook'] = nil` and it worked for me.

ulimit let you limit resources. I think it can be used to limit redis resources. (again I am new too.) So the better way might be figure how you want to configure ulimit and set the correct attribute rather than nil